# Adding a submenu to an existing menu in a Visual Studio 2013 extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix

I'm trying to build an extension in VS 2013 that adds a submenu to the Tools menu. Following the tutorials from microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb165739.aspx

The base example works fine and adds a brand new menu along the top menu bar but I'd like to add my submenu to the Tools menu. What I've done is changed the parent id in the menu section from IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS to IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS but nothing shows up.

Here is the snipped of code that I've changed.

```
<Menu guid="guidTopLevelMenuCmdSet" id="TopLevelMenu" priority="0x700" type="Menu">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS" />
    <!--<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS" />-->
```

Answer (score 6):

The parent of submenus or buttons must be a group (IDG_), not a menu (IDM_). You have a list of groups in the Tools menu in the section "Tools menu groups" of [GUIDs and IDs of Visual Studio Menus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118.aspx)

Comment: thank you, I was missing this important bit. Now menu is coming correctly.